# AutoComplete Using JQuery for ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

The ff example is from http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags" />
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

from this example I want to apply it in my ASP.NET project.

My concern is, is it possible to put the content of "availableTags" to a variable from code behind? If yes then how can I connect it to this code to accomplish the same thing?

I would appreciate your help.

Thank you!

Comment: I think you will have to use a script manager or some other mechanism to insert the values for you jquery data source into the dom on you asp.net page load, assuming you are using aspx pages. If you are using mvc then it is trivial.

Comment: Since you're using asp.net, why not use the built in autocomplete http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx

Comment: I tried it Yuriy but it doesn't work for me because or the complexity of the predefined class that we are using to access the database.

Comment: Well, you would just need to build a comma separated list of quoted strings and just use `var availableTags = [<%= MyQuotedStrings %>];` to output it directly within the array.  This is basic ASP.NET.

Comment: Solomon I would appreciate if you can provide me a sample.

Comment: Someone already has...

Comment: Thanks for asking this question to help many :)

Answer (score 6):

Script portion of the ASPX page:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    <%= GetAvailableTags() %>
  ];
  $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
});
</script>
```

Code behind:

```
public string GetAvaliableTags()
{
    var tags = new[] { "ActionScript", "Scheme" };
    return String.Join(",", tags.Select(x => String.Format("\"{0}\"", x)));
}
```

The `GetAvailableTags()` function's output will be directly written to the page at render time.

This is a 'quick and dirty' solution of course. If, for example, your auto-complete items contain special characters like quotes, you'll have to take a different approach.

Comment: Thanks I will try this. Don't worry we don't include special characters in the items. It's just a list of names from the database.

Comment: I just realize that yes it's really a 'quick and dirty' solution but for me it's a bit cryptic as of the moment since I haven't tried this before. :)

Comment: I have never used `<%= %>` syntax to bind a JavaScript array, nice! Filing this one away for later use!

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods as the conduit to the server-side called via jQuery to retrieve a list of `availableTags`, like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "YourPage.aspx/GetAutoComplete",
                    data: "{}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(msg) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now in code-behind on `YourPage.aspx`, create the page method, like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string[] GetAutoComplete()
{
    return new[]
    {
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
    };
}
```

Comment: Nice approach. I didn't realize you can create AJAX endpoints in ASP.NET this easily. I think your syntax is wrong though: duplicate header.

Comment: Ah yes, copy and paste got me. LOL. Updating answer.

Comment: I agree this is simpler approach compared to the other approach that I tried before that will force you to add something like AutoComplete.asmx.

Comment: Thanks Karl! I will try this as well.

Comment: @ChrisN.P. - great, glad we could help you out. Good luck. :-)

Comment: follow the ajax method only if you have large list of tags and required to get it from db